# Drop time calculation for Veritasium Chain Drop Experiment

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, free-fall

I'm referring to the [Chain Drop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-QFAB0gEtE) experiment conducted in Veritasium youtube channel.
[Experiment] : He stands at a height H with 2 identical weights (mass M each) - W1, unattached, and W2, tied to a massive chain (of length ~ H/2, and uniform linear mass density λ) attached to a railing at the same height as the weights. Now he drops the weights simultaneously. The weight attached to the chain (W2) hits the ground first, before the free-falling weight.

[Explanation] : The chain whips the weight around, faster than the free-falling weight. As W2 descends, parts of the chain go from falling to becoming stationary. So it's accelerating up. The tension required to accelerate the weight up, pulls down on the weight, accelerating it at a rate greater than the rate due to gravity. Hence, W2 reaches the ground first.

[Assumptions] : No air resistance. Chain to be treated as an ideal rope with mass. Masses are point objects.

[Question] : Can we derive a formula for the drop time t2 of W2? And compare it to t1 = (2h/g)^0.5 ? The video only presents a qualitative explanation.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the modern-day fascination with this problem can be traced back to two articles by Calkin & March from 1989:

- [The dynamics of a falling chain: I.](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/57/2/10.1119/1.16114)  Am. J. Phys. **57**, 154 (1989)
- [The dynamics of a falling chain: II.](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/57/2/10.1119/1.16115)  Am. J. Phys. **57**, 157 (1989).

The first of these deals with the motion of the hanging chain (as shown in the Veritasium video);  the other deals with the motion of a chain hanging over a peg.

It's been a while since I've read these papers (and I'm not on my campus computer, so the papers are behind a paywall for me right now);  but my recollection is that while an energy-conservation model does *better* at explaining the observed acceleration of the chain, it still isn't perfect.  A quick Googling of "falling chain problem" reveals a large number of papers in the years since then that attempt to refine this model.